# Is it possible to change the generator without knowing the private key used?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs

For example, prover sends P = xG and verifier somehow sends back P = xH without learning x.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, prover sends P = xG and verifier somehow sends back P = xH without learning x.

Yes; if the verify knows that $H = yG$, he just computes $P' = yP = xyG = xH$

Comment: What if the verifier does not know the discrete log H wrt to G?

Comment: Then it's the Computational Diffie-Hellman (CDH) problem - difficult in the groups we use in crypto

Comment: Note that this is essentially the Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau: Hey!  How am I supposed to maintain the illusion that I am wise and all-knowing, when people like you keep on pointing out that my answers are essentially trivial... :-)

Comment: Apologies! Next time I'll make sure to make a remark along the lines of "actually, this answer of poncho just solved in three lines a century-long open problem that Alan Turing himself had described as 'the greatest and probably hardest problem on computer science' in his seminal paper" :)